# Отслеживание ссылок-источников переходов по сайт

Tags: php

Можно ли узнать, с какой ссылки перешли на ваш сайт?

Предложили работу, написали:

> Вы регистрируетесь, указываете контактные данные и номер интернет-кошелька. У вас будет личный кабинет, где будет ваша индивидуальная ссылка на наш сайт с платным продуктом. Эту ссылку вы рекомендуете. По ней проходят и покупают, это все я узнаю. Эту информацию мне предоставит сервис, в котором будет ваш личный кабинет. Браузер не причем."

Это аферист?

Comment: @Zow, Согласно правилам форума, пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: я хочу понять, можно ли узнать, с какой ссылки перешли на сайт. Как пишет этот человек. Ведь согласно location этого узнать нельзя

Comment: По описанию это что-то похоже на партнерку. где ссылки вида www.com?ref=refcode . Где refcode твой код. Его учитывают при начислении процента. Пересмотрите свое видение на способы реализации данной задачи. По Аферист или нет - не похоже, судя с приведенного текста. Многие партнерские программы, в том числе и форекс-брокеры работают по подобному принципу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это известная схема при продвижении продуктов, дело в том, что Ваша уникальная ссылка будет содержать и Ваш уникальный идентификатор в системе, например http://supersoftware.com/?id=40734

Переходя по данной ссылке - сервер (независимо от платформы) может определить по идентификатору ?id=40734, что посетитель пришел и купил продукт именно по вашей ссылке и увеличить Ваш баланс на условную единицу.

Answer (score 5):

Неувязочка с тегом вопроса (html), заголовком вопроса и его содержимым.

1. Для того, чтоб узнать откуда пришёл пользователь на ваш сайт, надо воспользоваться элементом суперглобального массива $_SERVER - **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']**, но это уже PHP.
2. По поводу аферситы это или нет, вам надо было бы обратится не на **ХешКод**, а на форум **ТелепатКод**. Но его пока не открыли.
3. Единственное с чем согласен, так это то, что "*Браузер не причем*". ))